# Cannot find bug in simple .CMD file

Tags: windows, debugging, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I cannot find my bug, after `set /p sum=give nr %amount%:` it closes.
Does anybody have an Idea why ?
thanks anyway;-)

```
    ::Made By QluPreX 29/01/2015
@echo off
cls
color a
:SET_NUM
    set /p tot=how many numbers:
    cls
    set amount=1    
    set sum_tot=0
    echo %tot%?
    set /p y_or_n=is that correct (y/n) ? :
    if  %y_or_n%==y (
        cls
        goto:GIVE_NUM
    ) ELSE (
        cls
        goto:SET_NUM
    )
:GIVE_NUM
    set /p sum=give nr %amount%:
    set /a sum_tot=%sum_tot%+%sum%
    set /a amount=%amount%+1
    if /I %amount%==%tot%(
        goto:DISPLAY
    )ELSE(
        goto:GIVE_NUM
    )
:DISPLAY
    echo total is %sum_tot%
    pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you mean by `set /p sum=give nr %amount%:`

but

```
)ELSE(
```

Must be

```
) ELSE (
```

(spaces required)

equally,

```
if /I %amount%==%tot%(
```

must be

```
if /I %amount%==%tot% (
```